# How to instantiate my Content Provider up front?

Tags: android

In my application, I have created a ContentProvider.  Is there a way for me to instantiate this `ContentProvider` when my `apk` is started?

Right now, the ContentProvider only instantiates when someone does a query.

Answer (score 2):

What exactly do you mean by 'instantiate' your Content Provider? Generally you should be using a Content Resolver to access Content Providers rather than instantiating them directly.

If you want to initiate a query against your Content Provider when your application is first started, you can extend the `Application` class and override the `onCreate` method, making a query to your Content Provider from there.

If you go that way, you'll also need to modify the `<application>` node in your manifest to include an `android:name` attribute that specifies your new Application class implementation.